# Building few projects fail with MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, visual-c++, msbuild

All other C# project files are building with MSBuild scripts. 
But, few C++ related projects are failing with the below error -

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140')
>   cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, either click the
>   Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++
>   Projects...". Install v140 to build using the v140 build tools.

I am getting the above error when I try to build the project using command prompt and the same error is getting when trying to build using Jenkins. How should we fix this issue?

Comment: Have a look at what comes up when you put the error message in Google: [MSB8020](https://www.google.com/search?q=MSB8020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1) By creating one System Environment variable - `VCTargetsPath` with value - `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140`, solved  building the projects using command prompt on the build server.

But the above solution is not working when trying to build using Jenkins. The below solution resolved the issue.

Solution 2) Changed the build scripts to pass this parameter - /p:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140"

Answer (score 0):

> What’s your vs version? The C++ project you want to build seems to
>   come from VS2015.

If you are vs2013 or earlier,we can install [build tools 2015](https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/D/EEDF18A8-4AED-4CE0-BEBE-70A83094FC5A/BuildTools_Full.exe) to try to solve this issue.

Note: According to error message, the projects come from vs2015 and sometimes it may cause compatibility issues when we compile projects from higher vs versions.
So I prefer to suggest you to update vs to vs2015.

In addition: 
Right-click on the project name=>properties=>general=>platform toolset

, then you can find the toolset versions you have, and make sure v140 have installed successfully.

Comment: Right-click on the project name=>properties=>general=>platform toolset is showing as - Visual Studio 2015 (v140). And on that build server, Visual Studio multiple versions are present (2010, 12, 15, 17). I also installed the "build tools 2015". And still I see same error. Any other possible solutions for this?

Comment: @Apparao Sorry for that not works.                                                               And what vs version do you use to compile the C++ project? I meet same issue when compiling C++(2015) projects by vs2012, then i change the platform toolset from v140 to vs2012(v110) to get this solved.                       
However, my C++ project is a simple one, so we can't make sure if it works for projects with multiple assembly. And as i mentioned, to compile vs2015 projects, using vs2015 or higher versions is more suitable.