# Jenkins | Node-Gyp error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found

Tags: node.js, jenkins, msbuild, node-gyp, visual-studio-2019

I am new and trying to set up a new Jenkins Build server and I am trying to to automate a node addon api project. I am facing following issue only on Jenkins server even when I try to run the node-gyp on cmd prompt, it is working fine.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\jenkins_builds\Reporter-Backend\workspace\build\copy_binary.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\jenkins_builds\Reporter-Backend\workspace\node_modules\node-addon-api\src\nothing.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1

Node version v10.15.3
Node-Gyp v4.0.0
Jenkins v2.164.3
Visual Studio 2019
```

I have tried to set envirmont path as well as setting in Gyp file for correct msbuild path. But in Jenkins build is failed every time with above issue.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the project you want to build comes from VS2017 whose C++ ToolSet is V141.

And as you mentioned you use VS2019 whose Toolset is V142.

To fix it:

1.We can re-target the solution to V142 ToolSet, then the VS2019 msbuild tool builds it well (Open the .sln in VS2019, right-click solutionName and choose re-target)

2.Also, you can choose to install the ToolSet V141 in VS2019.

In VS2019, go Tools=>Get Tools and Features=> Install the C++ build tools for VS2017:

[image] (Assuming your project are in X64/X86, not Arm)

Click modify to install the V141 Toolset, and create a new C++ project, Right-click Project=>properties to check if we install ToolSet v141 successfully:

[image]

Also, there is possibility that you've installed the ToolSet, and the error you gets result from the wrong msbuild path or parameter.

So make sure the msbuild path for VS2019 is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Update:

Try settinging VCTargetsPath: VCTargetsPath= C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v150\ after installing the toolset in vs2019.

Comment: I already have above setup like you said. My problem is that Build not getting generated via Jenkins only. Using a normal CMD prompt I am able to generate Build.

Comment: @Random The same msbuild path? 1.Ok, please check if you set the `VCTargetsPath` system variable, and what's its value? If it exists, try removing it and check if it helps. 2. And for jenkins, it looks similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348624/building-few-projects-fail-with-msbuild), you can try changing the script and explicitly set the VCTargetsPath value.

Comment: The VCTargetsPath= C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v150\ after you install the toolset in vs2019.

Comment: It worked after setting VCTargetsPath for v150 path.
Thank you.

Comment: @Random Glad to know it helps! If my answer is helpful to resolve your issue, could you please help mark it as accepted answer, which benefits other members with similar issue:)